# Mysql SQLselect user-variable in if

Tags: mysql, variables, if-statement

Is is quite wired that the user-defined variable in the following sentence,

```
  SELECT   
           @f:=CONVERT(
             IF(@c<=>CatId  AND DATEDIFF(Date, @d)=1, @f, Date), DATE
           ) AS Begin,
           @c:=CatId, @d:=Date
  FROM     my_table  AS init
  ORDER BY CatId, Date
```

As show in here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fddbd/83, and my_table is given by:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  Id    INT(6) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL,
  CatId INT,
  Date  DATE,
  Rate  INT
);

INSERT INTO my_table
VALUES
  (000001, 12, '2009-07-07', 1),
  (000002, 12, '2009-07-08', 1),
  (000003, 12, '2009-07-09', 1),
  (000004, 12, '2009-07-10', 2),
  (000005, 12, '2009-07-15', 1),
  (000006, 12, '2009-07-16', 1),
  (000007, 13, '2009-07-08', 1),
  (000008, 13, '2009-07-09', 1),
  (000009, 14, '2009-07-07', 2),
  (000010, 14, '2009-07-08', 1),
  (000010, 14, '2009-07-10', 1);
```

more precisely, the variable `@f` is not pre-defined, and what's the logic mysql will do for the DateDiff?

Comment: and what's '<=>' mean? why just '<>'?

Comment: It's the null-safe equality operator. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to

Comment: @Barmar I see this, in fact, at first I think it is equal to `<>`, what a big misunderstanding! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first row it will use `NULL` for the values of all the variables. So it's equivalent to the following query that initializes them all explicitly

```
SELECT   
    @f:=CONVERT(
        IF(@c<=>CatId  AND DATEDIFF(Date, @d)=1, @f, Date), DATE
    ) AS Begin,
    @c:=CatId, @d:=Date
FROM my_table  AS init
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @f := NULL, @c := NULL, @d := NULL) AS vars
ORDER BY CatId, Date
```

It's generally not recommended to put the `ORDER BY` clause in the same level of the query as the processing. MySQL performs this differently depending on whether the columns in the `ORDER BY` are named in the `SELECT` clause. If they are, it performs the ordering *after* producing all the results, otherwise it uses it to order the rows in the table before processing them. The way to get predictable results is to use a subquery:

```
SELECT   
    @f:=CONVERT(
        IF(@c<=>CatId  AND DATEDIFF(Date, @d)=1, @f, Date), DATE
    ) AS Begin,
    @c:=CatId, @d:=Date
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM my_table
      ORDER BY CatId, Date)  AS init
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @f := NULL, @c := NULL, @d := NULL) AS vars
```

Since you're seeing different results on different MySQL versions, this might also depend on the version. Using the subquery should make it work consistently.

Comment: `CROSS JOIN` is a join with no conditions. It just performs a full cross product between the two tables. In this case, the subquery just returns one row.

Comment: And what's happens  on the second row to `@f`,`@c`,`@d`?

Comment: On the second row they all have the values that were assigned during the first row. That's the point of using variables, they allow you to carry values from one row to the next.

Comment: I thought your question was just about what happens when you use the variables before they're assigned, not a general misunderstanding of what variables are for.

Comment: But it seems then hard to understand the results is not changed in case I change the order of query row, as in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e6edb/1

Comment: `ORDER BY CatID, Date` puts them back in order before it does the assignments.

Comment: If you take out `ORDER BY`, you'll get different results: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e6edb/2

Comment: Maybe I should open another post, but the same table and query outputs different results, one is in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e102bc/5 it works fine, but the same table `t` with the same query does not work on my self hosted mysql (excude from phpmyadmin). The version of mysql server is `5.5.40-0+wheezy1`, which is higher than the SQLFiddle one.

Comment: I've added an explanation of the complications of `ORDER BY`.

Comment: That's it, then it works now. And I find the Cross Join is also necessary to make the results the same.

Comment: If you run the query twice in the same database connection, the variables will retain their values if you don't use the cross join to initialize them each time.